Iteration Level and Area Level are gone?
I've been using "Iteration Level X" and "Area Level X" fields in my queries. However, recently I found these fields are gone and I can no longer use them in query. In the backlog view it still shows these columns as I set these fields in columns before, but now in the column chooser I cannot longer add these fields to columns anymore.
I'd expect I can continue using "Iteration Level X" and "Area Level X" in queries and column chooser, in addition to "Iteration Path" and "Area Path".
It's quite annoying if this is an intentional change and I want to know how I can configure Azure Boards so that I can get these fields back.
Any suggestions?

I found this ticket and seems this is a known bug.
The latest update:
There is a fix released for this issue!

For more details, you can refer the release note Area and iteration level fields.

Oh, great. Thanks for the information, Miao!
However, the latest post on the thread says that this feature should have not been enabled and now it's turned off by design. This is disappointing and I'm sending a feedback for that.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Iteration-Level-2-has-disappeared/10685285#T-N10695370

Hi @KotaroYoshida, thanks for your feedback. Hope this feature comes back.

Hi @KotaroYoshida, there is a fix released for this issue! I have updated the answer.

Thanks for the notification, Miao! I still don't see that in my organization but I'm aware that it's said that it would take 2 - 3 weeks to be fully deployed so I'm looking forward to see that work for us.

Hi @miao-tian-msft, for record, now I can see iteration level X and area level Y shows up in my environment!
